# Separate the logic in projects Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, architecture, frontend

I have 3 projects Angular 2. They are written on  typescript. All the projects have the same models and services. How can I make them at a global level and then connect to each of the projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is:

1. Define your models in the separate project (folder).
2. Create package.json with `main` field pointing to your entry file ([sample](https://github.com/magnetnation/mgCore/blob/master/package.json)) inside the folder created.
3. If you do not want to make your lib public do not forget to set `"private": true`
4. In case of public package - publish it to npm and then consume it by running `npm install` for it from your other projects.
5. If it is a private package - copy it to your projects root directory (or other place within) and consume by
   `import * as myLib from "./path/to/myLib";`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've created own npm package. All work like need!